# How do I do a full installation of Linux onto a USB flash drive

Tags: usb, usb-installation

I can make live boot usb drives, but I want to know if/how it is possible to install a full version of Linux onto a 32 GB flash drive that i have. I have been trying to no avail so was wondering if I am even doing it correctly.

Comment: What have you tried?  Installing to a USB flash should be just like installing to any other device, but UEFI machines do have some problems with such an install (bugs 1173457 and 1229488).

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? And you have to partition in advance either way and only use Something else to install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/906857/installing-ubuntu-on-usb-and-booting-from-destop-with-uefi If external drive in UEFI you have to manually copy files if not the only drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338836

Answer (score 0):

Following is step by step for installing 16.04 LTS on a 32GB flash drive on an Intel machine.

Turn off and unplug the computer. (See note at bottom)
Remove the side from the case.
Unplug the power cable from the hard drive.
Plug the computer back in.
Insert the flash drive.
Insert the Live CD or Live USB.
Start the computer, the CD/USB should boot.
Select language
Select install Ubuntu.
Select Download updates while installing and Select Install third-party software.
Continue.

At "Installation type" select "Something else".
Continue

Confirm Device is correct.
Select "New Partition Table".
Click Continue on the drop down.

(Optional partition for use on Windows machine)
Click "Free space" and "+".
Make "Size:" about 10000 MB.
Select "Primary".
Location for the new partition = "Beginning of this space".
"Use as:" = "FAT32 file system".
And Mount point = "/windows".
Select "OK"

Click "free space" and then "+".
Select "Size:" = 5000 to 7000 megabytes, "Primary", "Beginning of this space", Ext4, and Mount point = "/" then OK.

(Optional home partition)
Click "free space" and then "+".
Select "Size:" = 1000 to 10000 MB, "Primary", Beginning, Ext2, and Mount point = "/home" then OK.

(Optional swap space, allows hibernation)
Click "free space" and then "+".
Select "Size:" = remaining space, (1000 to 2000 megabytes, or same size as RAM), "Primary", "Beginning of this space" and "Use as" = "swap area" then OK.

(Important)
Confirm "Device for boot loader installation" points to the USB drive. Default should be ok if HDD was unplugged.
Click "Install Now".

Select your location.
Continue.
Select Keyboard layout.
Continue.
Insert your name, computer name, username, password and select if you want to log in automatically or require a password.
Requiring a password to log in and selecting "Encrypt my home folder" are good options if you are worried about loosing your USB drive.
Select Continue.

Wait until install is complete.
Turn off computer and plug in the HDD.
Stick the side panel back on.

Note:
You may omit disabling the hard drive if, when partitioning you choose to install grub to the root of the usb drive you are installing Ubuntu to, (ie sdb not sdb1). Be cautious, many people have overwritten the HDD MBR.
The internal drive will be added to grub boot menu, you can revise grub later, if you wish.